# Is it must the client of Netty Server , be written using Netty framework?

Tags: netty

I need to ask , is it mandatory, if i have implemented my TCP server using Netty , to program my client also using Netty, to have the same channel handling ? , or can any TCP client written in Pure Java NIO without netty, work with any netty server without any issues in stream handling and encoding  ?

Additional part :

My server has a customizable logic in in the server encoder , decoder and login decoder, should i also replicate the same logic in client decoder and encoder?

Waiting your valuable reply,

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

No. Not necessary at all. Netty is a server and you can write the TCP client in any language or framework of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for response,but , i have specific logic in the server encoder and decoder, also login decoder for handshakes logic between client and server, is in that case, should i implement also the client encoder and decoder , or any client can work with that type of server?,

Comment: Sockets are just like a freight service. If you want to pack things  at source then you'll have to implement the unpacking logic at destination.

Comment: @AhmedHassenRomeh if your Netty server's decoder/encoder handlers are implemented in a way that they decode/encode the log-ing, business logic messages using a well defined binary format,(for example proto buffers), you don't need to use Netty for client application. If you are going to define the messages as POJOs and use Netty's Object Codecs, then you need to use netty.